# How to fit different canvas proportionately on top of image?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

My topic here is pretty straight forward for a project..

I saw lots of topics on the subject of resizing images into canvas... but what I'm trying to do here is the opposite.

I have a template image that isn't going to change unless it's a different screen size. However; I'd like to make it so the image in the form of a canvas fits inside the template image dimensions. I'd like to think of the template almost like a container, but since I will be using different images with different dimensions it's a little more complex.

I'm trying to make it so the image created inside the canvas element fits regardless of it's size fits proportionately inside the dimensions of the #tee element.

```
<body>
<div id="obj-container">
<canvas id="obj"></canvas>
<img id="tee" src="https://doc-04-6s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/qhq5e6giuhl9ifpegip5ens14q2k3js8/8krn1u04pvhor8f561eg93ipbn8hjh2e/1569607200000/16313464075852650790/11150445017567734732/0B3ubyt3iIvkaUlpHVEpDTGhjQzg?e=view"></img></div>
```

Here is an actual example on Codepen https://codepen.io/andrew-squire/pen/JjPqPey

Comment: You want the canvas size to keep its aspect ratio / proportions, but scale to fit the size of the tee image? And do you want them to overlap?

Comment: Yes the intrinsic dimensions of the tee image is 2400 x 1800 (think of it as a container type element.) -- https://ibb.co/pxrCJKv

But I'm trying to get it so the canvas fits proportionately fits inside of that image (tee image) (visually) not literally.